# Recover data from accidental update

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I have done an incorrect update and hence I restored the DB with a backup from the previous day. I have not taken a copy of the corrupted data before restoring the backup. Is there any possibility to get back the data lost between the creation of back up file and restoring the file?

Thanks for saving my job

Comment: is the database in full recovery mode? Are the transaction logs available?

Comment: The DB is in full recovery mode. Transaction Logs are not enabled

Comment: The full recovery mode requires logs backups: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you did not take a log backup between the full yesterday and your restore today, then no, everything changed since yesterday is gone.

In a best case "accidently deleted data" scenario, the process is to take a log backup to capture the "tail"of the log, restore a full backup of the DB to an alternate location, restore log backups using STOPAT to get to the point right before the accidental delete and copy the data.

If you don't have the room to restore an extra copy, or the accidental deletion is severe enough that you must restore over the existing database, then it is twice as important to backup up the tail of the log.

Comment: Going from OP's comment "Transaction Logs are not enabled" I'd say the tail of the log becomes a huge t-log backup. Hopefully he has full backups to start on.